# filter sqldatasource and display values that not equals filterexpression

Tags: c#, asp.net, filter, sqldatasource

I just want to filter my sqldatasource and display all values that not equals the filterexpression. Somehow like this:

```
        SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression != "something='something'";
```

Is there any possibility to do so?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: `SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = "something <> 'something'";`?

Comment: If i add this i´ll get no results in the Listview. Is there something special i need to consider?

Comment: Just remember that the `FilterExpression` is essentially a SQL `WHERE` clause. So for example, if you wanted all employees with last names that aren't "Smith", you would do `SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = "EMPL_LAST_NAME <> 'Smith'";`.

Comment: Got the problem. The later entrys of the datasource were empty. Now it works fine. Thank you!